# Performing query with like operator

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to make a query according to starting and ending character and also the length of the string. Suppose,in my db i have hello,how,hurray,honey.I want to take honey from the db and so I want to make a query such as it will find the string starting with "h" and end with "y" and the length of the word is 5. I have written a query is it right?

```
Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + MYDATABASE_TABLE
                + " where LENGTH(`" + MYDATABASE_FIELD + "`) = " + len
                + " and `" + MYDATABASE_FIELD + "` LIKE `" + part1 + "%"
                + part2 + "`", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should have condition something like this,

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE LENGTH(colName) = 5 AND
      colName LIKE 'h%s'
```

Answer (score 1):

The second `LIKE` operator is a string, not a table/column name, so you must not quote it with backticks.
Furthermore, using parameters avoids string formatting problems altogether:

```
Cursor c = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM `" + MYDATABASE_TABLE + "` " +
      "WHERE LENGTH(`" + MYDATABASE_FIELD + "`) = " + len + " " +
        "AND `" + MYDATABASE_FIELD + "` LIKE ?",
    new String[] { part1 + "%" + part2 });
```